# Get Gate Activation of GRU-Cells in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I implemented a standard RNN in Tensorflow (0.12) using the classes

- tf.python.ops.rnn_cell.GRUCell
- tf.nn.dynamic_rnn

I am interested in the gates and which values they take during. Unfortunately the function dynamic_rnn doesn't support this and just gives the 'output' and 'state' (The final hidden state). In the code of the GRUCell the gates are called 'r' and 'u' for reset and update.

**Is there a clever way to save the values of the gates over time or do I have to write my own GRU cell?**

Thanks!

Comment: Set up a `variable_scope`, then get the internal variables using `get_variables(scope)`.

Comment: With this I would get the trainable variables and could read their value. I want the values of the gate activation itself over time, not the values of the gate network variables. But thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to figure out the same problem as well. I don't have the full solution but maybe we can help each other out.

If you do: `names =[n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]`

This will give you a list of all the names of the nodes in the graph. For Rnn the out put for `names` should look some what like this

```
.
'RNN/Shape',
'RNN/strided_slice/stack',
'RNN/strided_slice/stack_1',
.
. 
.
'RNN/transpose'
.
```

Then you can use `get_operation_by_name` to get the operation you want to look at.

```
 rnn_transpose=tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('RNN/transpose').outputs[0]
```

From that you can run the `eval()` with your regular `sess` and `feed_dict`

```
 rnn_transpose.eval(session=sess,feed_dict =feed_dict)
```

The problem here is now we have to find which operations in the graph correspond to the proper gate operations.

Comment: This looks like a good idea, but it is incomplete. If you did find the right names and get the gate values you were looking for, it would be great if you could add those to the answer.